# How to mutate paneldata with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have panel data (person-year combination) for which I need to investigate the impact that your partner's characterics (several "x") have on your outcome variable (y). Everything is given in one tibble/dataframe. Partner information is given by "pid".

```
paneldata = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), time=seq(1:3), pid=c(3,3,NA,4,4,3,1,1,2,2,2,NA),
                           y=c(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), x=c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32), 
                           x_partner=c(27,28,NA,30,31,29,21,22,26,24,25,NA))

library(dplyr)
paneldata %>%
  group_by(id, time) %>%
  mutate(x_pid = x[pid])
```

I want to achieve `x_partner`, but what I have to far is `x_pid`. I'm trying to catch the index, while running through `group_by` "id" and "time", get the "pid" (not unique!) and look at x at combination pid-time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be grouping by id, only by time.

```r
paneldata %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(x_partner = x[match(id, pid)])
```

Comment: Perfect and elegant solution, that's what I expected `dplyr` to provide. Thanks